Maximum principle for reaction diffusion equation?
Consider the heat equation $$u_t = u_{xx} \;\; \text{ for } \;\; x\in \Omega, t \in [0,+\infty) \,. $$
The strong maximum principle states that if the solution $u$ attains its maximum in the interior of $\Omega$, then $u$ must be constant.
The weak maximum principle states that the solution $u$ attains its maximum on the spatial boundary or at its initial condition, i.e. $u$ attains its maximum on $\text{int}(\Omega) \times \{ 0 \} \cup \partial \Omega \times [0,T]$.
Now consider a perturbation by a Lipschitz continuous reaction term $f$:
$$ u_t = u_{xx} + f(u)\,.$$
Under what conditions on $f$ does the maximum principle still hold? Is there a weaker version of the maximum principle that can hold for Lipschitz $f$?
